# I want to select random sub matrix around value.

Tags: matlab

[image]

I want to value in random sub matrix..

For example..
First step, Select One random matrix(nxn) in matrix "A". (select search space..)
Second step, Select middle value from this matrix.

[image]

also, Is it available?, first select "22" (It is random number in total matrix) , second find the matrix around "22".

I am rookie using MATLAB, Now I am studying hard about MATLAB. this is very interest! And I am sorry because I have very poor english ability..

Comment: Try `randi` (type `help randi` in the Matlab command window to learn more about it)

Comment: @David Thank you David. But I can select random number using radni, but I can't select the range around selected numer..

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. If you select a random value from A, then this is just a scalar. Since you say you want to select a search space then I guess you actually want a random vector or subset of vectors of A. Do you want to sample a random direction from a space created by the column span or row span of a matrix? Please clarify carefully.

Comment: @MichaelJ Thank you for comment :) , You are correct. I want a subset of vectors of Matrix A. and also I need the middle value in subset.

Comment: You want to randomly select vectors from A and then find the mean? Be careful because selecting a random column of A and selecting a random direction from the space spanned by the columns of A is not the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelJ I edited my question, I added picture my idea. :) My english ability is poor. so It is very hard understand of all :)

Comment: It's fine. I just want to make sure I answer the right question. Thanks for the picture, that clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a matrix A, this code will randomly select a partition of size `npart`. While one could use `randperm` as in the original answer, @LuisMendo points out in comments that `randi` is simpler (and in fact it is faster as well).

```
npart = 3 ;
[m,n] = size(A) ;
ix = randi(m-npart+1) ;
iy = randi(n-npart+1) ;
X = A(ix:ix+npart-1,iy:iy+npart-1) ;
```

Of course the most efficient way to do this is to only sample a single random variable and convert the index back:

```
[m,n] = size(A) ;
ind = randi( (n-npart+1)*(m-npart+1) ) ;
[ix,iy] = ind2sub([m-npart+1,n-npart+1],ind) ;
X = A(ix:ix+npart-1,iy:iy+npart-1) ;
```

Comment: Why `randperm(m-npart+1,1)` etc? `randi(m-npart)` seems simpler

Comment: @LuisMendo No idea why I wrote it that way. Habit? But it's a good point. I tested it and `randi` is cleaner syntax and also faster than `randperm`, so I edited the answer. Thanks!